# huge pages header file on centos is zero bytes

Tags: centos

I am trying to use the huge page API in Linux CentOS, the header file `hugetlbfs.h` is empty (i.e.: it exists, but it is zero bytes).

```
/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-358.14.1.el6.x86_64/include/config/hugetlbfs.h
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Alternatively, how do you use transparent huge pages to enable huge pages for an application without code changes?

Answer (score 3):

That particular file is part of the package kernel-devel-2.6.32-358.14.1.el6.x86_64. On a later system I have to hand it is 0 bytes too.

There is a package called `libhugetlbfs-devel` which contains `/usr/include/hugetlbfs.h` that's probably the package that you want to install.

For future reference the yum command can be used to search for files e.g.

```
yum provides */hugetlbfs.h
```

will search for and report the names of packages that contain the file anmes hugetlbfs.h